# Resource management in OpenGL using C++ and Python

Tags: python, c++, boost-python

I created a resource loader in OpenGL, and exposed it to Python, there is a function called:

```
Texture* tex = ResourceManager->loadTexture('name.png')
```

Then I keep the texture name in a vector list, so next time when I want to load it I will check if it is loaded already, if it is then return it with that pointer.

However when I want to unload it, I don't know how many times it has been used, if I unload it directly, it will crash, because the same pointer are used a lot times, all my class has been exposed to Python.

I was wondering if I can leave all this trouble to Python (automatic unload), and still keep track of what texture I loaded and reuse it?

ps:

```
platform: linux-x64
gcc: 4.8.3
python    c++   boost-python,
editor:kdevelop
```

Comment: You could move all the caching to Python. You could also use a smart pointer, in particular a combination of `shared_ptr` and `weak_ptr` could be used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Boost.Python will correctly use C++ 11 or boost shared_ptr. Just return a boost::shared_ptr instead and reference counting will be taken care of across the language boundary as well as in your C++ code.